# 500 internal server error, but fine on page refresh

Tags: wordpress

I have a WordPress installation that I'm currently working on. Every page that I visit gives a 500 internal server error, but when I refresh the page it works fine. What could be causing this?

Comment: it's happens to me sometimes. check, do you have installed any cache plugin. try to turn it of, and see, is there the same effect. also, check your .htaccess.

Comment: I've deactivated the cache plugin but the problem persists. The .htaccess is just the default. Can't see any problem there.

Comment: same problem with me, did you find a solution?